# Is it necessary to call .isSuccess?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I need to read the content of a collection in real-time. Here is what I have tried:

```
override fun getItems() = callbackFlow {
    val listener = db.collection("items").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        val response = if (snapshot != null) {
            val items = snapshot.toObjects(Item::class.java)
            Response.Success(items)
        } else {
            Response.Error(e)
        }
        trySend(response).isSuccess //???
    }
    awaitClose {
        listener.remove()
    }
}
```

And it works fine. The problem is that I don't understand the purpose of `.isSuccess`. Is it mandatory to be added?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for commenting but I'm not sure I understand. I use a SnapshotListener because I need to see the changes in real-time. For example, when a new item is added, then I want to be notified in real-time. Is there another approach?

Comment: Never mind, I just woke up and misread your code! What I said would only be true with Query.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trySend()` returns a `ChannelResult` object which contains the result of the operation. If `ChannelResult.isSuccess` returns `true` then the `response` had been successfully sent, otherwise the operation has been failed for some reason (maybe because of the buffer overflow) or because of a coroutine had been finished. You may handle it if you want, but usually it's omitted. Or you may log this result.

Comment: So, it's absolutely safe to omit `.isSuccess`, if I don't need to log the resut, right?

Comment: It’s safe, but it’s theoretically possible you could drop items and be failing to react if the buffer is full. But that’s very unlikely to happen I should think.